# Is there any possible way to call a external php page in wordpress inside another wordpress page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-pages

In my case I have created a page named `test.php` inside my theme folder. I have a specific html structure in `test.php` file. I don't include header and footer files here. I hard code them in this file because they are different.**I validate user details using `$_SESSION` in `function.php`.** Now what I want to do is, I want to validate the `SESSION`. If the **SESSION is false** I need to load the `test.php` file, **else I will follow Wordpress flow**.

Comment: You can use `get_template_part`. First check session validity then you can use this function to add a page within the page.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: I want to load the `test.php`  page individually. It's not about loading the page inside another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned:

> I validate user details using $_SESSION in function.php

So I'm assuming you have the validation part down, and are struggling with the redirection to `test.php`. You can achieve the redirect by hooking in to the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action.

Inside your `functions.php`, add:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if (!session_is_validated()) {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/test.php' );
        exit;
    }   
});
```

Comment: It's loading the `test.php` inside all the wordpress pages. It's not what I want to happen. I want to load only the `test.php` file which has the complete **HTML DOM**. When the session is valid I want to load `test.php` file without intercepting with any other wordpress pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to validate just the session, then something like this should be enough:

```
function IsAdmin() {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user_level'])){
        return false;
    }

    return ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1337);
}
```

Comment: Session validation is not the issue sir.I want to call the custom page when it's valid.